# Mapbox map not fitting the available width when trying to hide the sidebar, after the exit of the full-screen mode

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, mapbox

I noticed a weird behavior of the Mapbox map component. I have a MapView component that consists of a Navbar, Map, Sidebar, and Footer. When I open the sidebar and I toggle the full-screen mode and try to hide the sidebar, the map canva doesn't fit the available width **(see the attached screenshot).**

Here is my code:

**MapView.js**

```
import { useState } from "react";

import Footer from "../../components/Footer/Footer.component";
import Map from "../../components/Map/Map.components";
import NavBar from "../../components/NavBar/NavBar.components";

import "./MapView.styles.scss";
import SideBar from "../../components/SideBars/SideBar.component";

const INITIAL_ACTIVE_OPTIONS = {
  primaryNav: null,
  secondaryNav: null,
};

const MapView = () => {
  const [activeNavs, setActiveNavs] = useState(INITIAL_ACTIVE_OPTIONS);
  const [sideBarVisibility, setSideBarVisibility] = useState(false);

  const handleNavClick = (navName) => {
    switch (navName) {
      case "Drawing":
        if (navName !== activeNavs.primaryNav) {
          setActiveNavs({ primaryNav: navName, secondaryNav: "Overlay" });
          setSideBarVisibility(true);
        } else {
          setActiveNavs({ ...activeNavs, primaryNav: null });
        }
        break;
      case "Overlay":
        if (navName === activeNavs.primaryNav) {
          setActiveNavs({ ...activeNavs, primaryNav: null });
          setSideBarVisibility(false);
        } else if (navName === activeNavs.secondaryNav) {
          setActiveNavs({ ...activeNavs, secondaryNav: null });
          setSideBarVisibility(false);
        } else {
          setActiveNavs({ ...activeNavs, primaryNav: navName });
          setSideBarVisibility(true);
        }
        break;
      default:
        if (
          navName !== activeNavs.primaryNav &&
          navName !== activeNavs.secondaryNav
        ) {
          setActiveNavs({ ...activeNavs, primaryNav: navName });
          if (
            navName === "Layers" ||
            navName === "Info" ||
            navName === "Legend"
          )
            setSideBarVisibility(true);
        } else {
          setActiveNavs({ ...activeNavs, primaryNav: null });
          if (
            navName === "Layers" ||
            navName === "Info" ||
            navName === "Legend"
          )
            setSideBarVisibility(false);
        }
        break;
    }
  };

  const getSideBarContent = () =>
    Object.values(activeNavs).filter(
      (activeNavItem) =>
        activeNavItem === "Layers" ||
        activeNavItem === "Overlay" ||
        activeNavItem === "Info" ||
        activeNavItem === "Legend"
    )[0];

  return (
    <div className="container-app">
      <NavBar />
      <div
        className={
          sideBarVisibility
            ? "mapview-sidebars-shown"
            : "mapview-sidebars-hidden"
        }
      >
        {sideBarVisibility && <SideBar activeNav={getSideBarContent()} />}
        <Map />
      </div>
      <Footer activeNavs={activeNavs} handleNavClick={handleNavClick} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default MapView;
```

**MapView.styles.scss**

```
.container-app {
  display: grid;
  width: 100vw;
  padding: 0;
  grid-template-rows: 56px calc(100vh - 112px) 56px;
  user-select: none;
}

.mapview-sidebars-hidden {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100vw;
}

.mapview-sidebars-shown {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 370px calc(100vw - 370px);
}

.map-container {
  height: 100%;
}

.cursor-coordinates-container {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 70px;
  right: 0px;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

**Map.component.jsx**

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import mapboxgl from "mapbox-gl";

import "./Map.styles.scss";

//Defining mapbox key
mapboxgl.accessToken =
  "KEY_ACCESS_TOKEN";

//Defining mapbox arabic label support
mapboxgl.setRTLTextPlugin(
  "https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/plugins/mapbox-gl-rtl-text/v0.2.3/mapbox-gl-rtl-text.js",
  null,
  true // Lazy load the plugin
);

const Map = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    //Instaniate Map object
    const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: "map-container",
      style: "mapbox://styles/youssefaitali/cli7l6oey02ov01pr84tbhkbc",
      center: [-6.361245, 32.32947],
      zoom: 7,
      attributionControl: true,
    });

    map.addControl(new mapboxgl.NavigationControl(), "top-left");
    map.addControl(new mapboxgl.FullscreenControl(), "top-left");
  }, []);

  return <div id="map-container" />;
};

export default Map;
```

**Map.styles.scss**

```
.map-container {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

How can we ensure that the map fits the available width after closing the sidebar?

**Screenshot:**

[image]